# Moving the camera jerkily Unity,C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a puzzle game with drag-and-drop mechanics. Moving objects is implemented through Configurable Joint. When you click the left mouse button, I put the object attached to the player's body in the Conected body of the dragged object

[Joint parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6rgd.png)

[Player object hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE1QJ.png)

[RigidBody of the dragged object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmqih.png)

Hand's location depends on the player's camera rotation, the rotation script:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _Body;
private float _SensitivityHor = 9.0f, _RotationX = 0, _SensitivityVert = 5.0f, _MinimumVert = -45.0f, _MaximumVert = 45.0f;
void FixedUpdate()
{ 
    //Camera rotation
    Vector3 CameraAngles = transform.localEulerAngles;
    _RotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _SensitivityVert;
    _RotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_RotationX, _MinimumVert, _MaximumVert);
    float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _SensitivityHor;
    float rotationY = CameraAngles.y + delta;
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_RotationX, rotationY, 0);
    //Body rotation
    Vector3 BodyAngles = _Body.transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 _BodyrotationY = new Vector3(BodyAngles.x, CameraAngles.y, BodyAngles.z);
    _Body.transform.eulerAngles = _BodyrotationY;
}
```

The problem is that when you rotate the camera objects move jerkily (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gn4HS4NIndg), but on the scene all looks fine, I can not figure out what the problem is, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the rigidbody of the dragged object, after turning off the interpolation and changing the collision detection to discrete, the camera stopped moving jerkily:
[Fixed Rigidbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6TOS.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).